# What is difference between FTPClient and FTPSClient?

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming, apache-commons-net

what is difference between org.apache.commons.net.ftp.**FTPClient** and org.apache.commons.net.ftp.**FTPSClient** in java?

Comment: FTP, FTPS(ecured)?

Comment: I copy-pasted your question title on ddg, and this question wasn't even the first search result :) Which means that just typing it on internet would've gotten you the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

The [`FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) is used for plain FTP, the [`FTPSClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html) for FTP over SSL, as you could have read in the JavaDoc.